# Issue on Hiding Overflow in Bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/Fz4CW/2/) and let me know why the css `overflow:hidden` rule is not working for `.switch` class?
Please be informed that I do not want to change any thing in buttons and Switch mark ups and need to keep them as they are (Must not change the `col-lg-x` sizes)

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Switch</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="switch col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                <button class="btn btn-primary norightradius col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">Yes</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary noradius col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">New Model</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary noleftradius col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">No</button>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a shot of the required result

[image]

Comment: I deleted my answer since it probably doesn't apply from your explanation, but maybe if you update the question and find an example or screenshot of your desired result that would help.

Comment: Ok Dan thanks any way, I updated the question with a screenshot of the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bootstrap grid system is based upon 12 columns.  If you add up the columns consumed by your Yes button, title bar, and No button, you'll see that you've got 13 columns.

Just resize the title bar to be 10 columns instead of 11.

Change

```
<button class="btn btn-primary noradius col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">New Model</button>
```

To

```
<button class="btn btn-primary noradius col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">New Model</button>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonjonash/Fz4CW/6/

---

And if you'd like the button to be hidden at certain screen sizes, try using the responsive utility classes(like `hidden-sm` or `hidden-xs`): http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Oh, and why does it wrap? The bootstrap grid classes use `float:left` to arrange the grid items.  `overflow:hidden` only has the effect of *containing* floats, not hiding them.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I guess the hidden trick can help me to fix this